# Make Scatter Plot in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make scatter plot as shown, but instead of Integer values I need string, As shown in pic. You can understand it like QWE is a firm who is having 1 project pending with ABC company, 10 pending with CDE, 5 pending with HIJ and same for others.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIUDm.jpg)

Comment: Nice, Good luck

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.